# Java get path of executing jar without .jar file

Tags: java, path, resources

I am trying to export my app into jar using intelij Idea artifacts. I export everything except for resources (14,5GB is in my opinion too much for .jar file) so I have put `/res` folder inside same folder as jar.

Right now my structure looks like this:

```
/SAR.jar
/res/colors/
/res/icons/
/res/map/
```

However I cant access this resources. I am using the following code to get path:
 dir = new `File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath() + "/res/icons/");`

It works when running from IDE and it prints correct location. But when I build an artifact and run it through cmd I get the null pointer and it prints this path: `D:/JavaProject/SAR/out/artifacts/SAR_jar/SAR.jar/res/icons`. But my resources are not inside jar file they are only in same directory.

Any ideas? I have done only android projects in path and I simply cant get this resources system with jars to work.

Thanks in forward

Comment: Let me know if my proposition does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the ressources with a path dependent of your source code location, which is obviously not the case since you separated the code (or bytecode in the case of the jar) and the ressources. You must access them with a path relative to the jar or an absolute path.

I think you just need the following path (if the jar was ran from the directory containing the jar) :

```
new File("res/icons/icon.png")
```

Comment: it works but I mus still put getClass().getResources() before that if I want to compile it in IDE but thank you

Comment: It depends on the directory you mark as the working directory for your IDE. As long as you can use the same path in both cases, it's fine